# does WriteLine() in StreamWriter of network stream always deliver whole line?

Tags: c#, networkstream

question is simple: does WriteLine() in StreamWriter of network stream always deliver whole line? Or there are some limitations? for example it only delivers lines of some size.

My point is, if I call WriteLine(some very long string on 1 line (10000000 characters for example)), will ReadLine() of StreamReader receive it just as I sent it? Or it will receive only some part?

Comment: At a string that long, maybe a physical problem like RAM, Scratch space, addressable space might come into play... But I believe as long as you do not .Close, .Flush or add a line terminator then it saves it as one continuous line.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `ReadLine` on a `StreamReader` at the other end of the stream will always read a complete line (or produce `OutOfMemoryException`), but that's a property of [`ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) more than the network stream. At the network level, and for the `NetworkStream`, it *may* have been split into multiple separate sends and receives.

`ReadLine` doesn't return until it sees a newline sequence.

---

(Caveat - if the string that you pass to `WriteLine` contains, internally, newline sequences, then you'll only receive that portion of the string up until the first newline sequence)

Answer (score 1):

It will write and read it **ALL**, regardless.

For example, only earlier today I was working with `BigIntegers` and using a stream writing numbers with over **183,000 digits** using `WriteLine` (albeit, it took a while!).

Answer (score 1):

`WriteLine` may split your string up into many packets, but as long as you're using `ReadLine` on the other end, you don't need to care.

`ReadLine` will always read a whole line, whether it consists of multiple packets or not, providing the connection does not fail (and there's enough memory, etc).

To be more precise: your `StreamWriter` will always deliver the entire string to your NetworkStream, which may or may not send it all at once, depending on a number of factors, including of string, network configuration, etc.  On the other end, a similar thing happens.  NetworkStream.Read will read as much as it gets at a time, passing it all onto StreamReader, but if you're using `StreamReader.ReadLine`, the method won't return anything until it's got a complete line.